Sine integral and p-variation
Consider the sine integral function $\text{Si}(x):=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin y}{y}dy$. Also define the $p$-variation of $\text{Si}(x)$ as
$$V_p :=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\text{Si}(x_{i+1}) - \text{Si}(x_i)|^p: 0=x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n<\infty\right\},$$
where the supremum is taken over all partitions $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $(0,\infty)$.
Clearly,
$$V_p :=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}\frac{\sin y}{y}dy\right|^p: 0=x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n<\infty\right\}.$$
It is also clear the the supremum is $\infty$ for $p=1$, so the total variation of $\text{Si}(x)$ is infinite. I am trying to figure out if 2-variation (or $p$-variation for any other $p>1$) is finite. However, I have not been able to find a good upper bound or a counterexample so far. Would appreciate any hints!
